# include custom config file in dotnet pack

Tags: nuget, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a config file in a .netstandard2.0 project, and I'd like to include it in the same directory when packing, I already have this in csprof file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="load.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

and when I build it with `dotnet build`, the config file indeed was copied to output directory, but when `dotnet pack`, the nugget only includes the .dll, not the .config file, how can I include this config file in nugget package?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to add `Pack="true"` property:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="load.config" Pack="true">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

You may also need to specify  `PackagePath` property as well. I have found sample in [files section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#files).